# How do I configure printing to format properly?

Tags: civireport

We have a WordPress install that has never had the report printing formatted properly.  A report list does not have columns and rows with lines around cells.  Attached is an example from my system and one from the CiviCRM demo WordPress site.

What do we need to do to get properly formatted reports.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can I ask what versions of WP and CiviCRM you're using? Also whether the PDF formats correctly or if it's also missing table borders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug that is fixed in 4.6.11](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17511)--I discovered it on a client's site.  Basically, if your report doesn't have the header explicitly saved in the report settings, the header is blank rather than the default.  The default header contains the CSS to make your report look like it should.

The simplest solution is to upgrade, or you can apply the [diff](https://github.com/agh1/civicrm-core/commit/0642ec63cdf72ac9c4374b4815b2995a8bb90310).

Finally, a rough option is to edit the header and footer manually.  Your header should be:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>CiviCRM Report</title>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
    <style type="text/css">@import url(/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/css/print.css);</style>
  </head>
  <body><div id="crm-container">
```

and the footer should be

```
<p><img src="/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/i/powered_by.png" /></p></div></body>
```

You'll need to paste this in for each report, so it's more efficient to just upgrade, but if you're in a pinch trying to get the report out right away, this will help.

Comment: Thanks!  The header/foots code seems to have fixed my problem.  I will upgrade as soon as I can.